# [metatrader4]Market open/close event

Tags: metatrader4

I am wondering is there is a market close/open event, or a way to catch the point at which markets close on Friday and start on Monday.

I am implementing a Web-socket server that serves market feed data, and need the events to stop/restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MT4 does not provide such event, however there is configuration method which allows you to get such information:

```
    var timeConfiguration = manager.CfgRequestTime();
```

`timeConfiguration` will contain information about open hours in property `Days` which will contain 7 elements(one per day of week) and each element will have 24 childs(one per each hours). One means that market is open and 0 means that market is closed